# how to avoid segmentation fault when opening file within loop?

Tags: c, file, loops

When attempting to open a file (defined by event->name) I'm consistently getting a segmentation fault (core dumped). The closest I've got to preventing this issue is by altering "rb" to "r", and removing the hashing function below it - including "fclose(ftest)" - however I'd not consider that progress...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int fd;
        int wd;
        unsigned char c[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        int i;
        SHA512_CTX mdContext;
        int bytes;
        unsigned char data[1024];
        const int event_size = sizeof(struct inotify_event);
        const int buf_len = 1024 * (event_size + FILENAME_MAX);
        FILE *ftest;

        fd = inotify_init();

        if (fd < 0) {
          perror("inotify_init");
        }

        wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/home/joe/Documents", IN_CREATE);

        while (1) {
          char buff[buf_len];
          int no_of_events, count = 0;

          no_of_events = read (fd, buff, buf_len);
          while (count < no_of_events) {
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&buff[count];
            if (event->len) {
              if (event->mask & IN_CREATE)
              if(!(event->mask & IN_ISDIR)) {
                printf("The file %s has been created\n", event->name);

                ftest=fopen(event->name, "rb");  //segmentation fault 
                                                 //occurs here
                SHA512_Init (&mdContext);        
                while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, ftest)) != 0)
                    SHA512_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);
                SHA512_Final (c,&mdContext);
                for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) printf("%02x", c[i]);
                printf (" %s\n", ftest);
                fclose (ftest);
                fflush(stdout);
              }
            }
            count += event_size + event->len;
          }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Having ran this through Valgrind it does not provide any details of errors before the segmentation fault, and once the fault occurs does not provide details thereafter.

Comment: Your `event` is likely pointing to some invalid memory. Check your ranges.

Comment: `read()` returns `ssize_t`, not `int`.

Comment: printf (" %s\n", ftest);  -- what is that supposed to do?

Comment: @MK. Cause a `SIGSEGV`?  That's certainly UB.

Comment: the ftest variable is NULL and your read crash basically

Comment: you need to check what you read from the file. Most likely your offsets are misaligned and you are getting bad stuff in the name. As min you can `assert(count <=  num_of_event)` after it  gets incremented.

Comment: Most importantly -- whoever voted to close this: you [were wrong to do so].

Comment: Are you sure the segfault occurs on this line: `ftest=fopen(event->name, "rb")`? What is the output generated by `printf("The file %s has been created\n", event->name);` right before the segfault? Can you reproduce this with a debugger?

Comment: Oups: `printf (" %s\n", ftest);` is UB, `ftest` is a `FILE*` and not a pointer to a valid string.

Comment: OT:  when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`  Which will also eliminate the two warning messages about unused parameter `argc` and `argv[]`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `if (event->mask & IN_CREATE)
     if(!(event->mask & IN_ISDIR))` this would be much better written as: `if ( (event->mask & IN_CREATE) && (!(event->mask & IN_ISDIR)) )`

Comment: regarding: `printf (" %s\n", ftest);`  As mentioned this is undefined behavior.  Suggest: `printf (" %p\n", (void*)ftest);

Comment: regarding: `int bytes;` and `while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, ftest)) != 0)`  The function: `fread()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int` So the declaration of `bytes` should be: `size_t bytes;`

Comment: regarding: `ftest=fopen(event->name, "rb");`  when calling fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "fopen failed" );` to properly display your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the function failed to `stderr`

Comment: OT: variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage`  (or better, both)  Names like `c`, `wd`, etc are meaningless even in the current context

Comment: OT: regarding: `no_of_events = read (fd, buff, buf_len);`  the function `read()` returns a `ssize_t`,  not a `int`  Suggest changing the declaration of `no_of_events` from `int` to `ssize_t`  And because the returned value can be 0 or even <0, should properly check the value before continuing

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 1024.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: @Jabberwocky apologies for unresponsiveness - I have been ill and way from my computer. As for your first comment the generated output is "The file *filename* has been created" (where filename is literally the name of a file which has been moved into that directory).  As for your second comment you are correct - that was an error on my part - I was more focused on trying to get the file open than anything else.

Comment: @user3629249 I appreciate all that information! I'm a novice at C and what you've commented will really help me in the future. I'll define the "magic" numbers from here on out also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is that you are not checking any return values.  Every function call that returns something must be checked and handled.  In particular you are not checking return value of this:

```
ftest=fopen(event->name, "rb");  //segmentation fault
```

if it returns null (e.g. because `event->name` contains file name, not full path and you are not running in the directory you are monitoring), you will get an error.

You are also not checking this

```
wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/home/joe/Documents", IN_CREATE);
```

and possibly others.

The other problem is that you are printing file handle as a string here:

```
printf (" %s\n", ftest);
```

Also in order to get useful information in debugger and in valgrind you need to build with debug info (gcc -g)

Comment: @Gerhardh I dont follow.  His seg fault is almost certainly result of calling read() on a null (value of ftest).  Had he checked his return value, there would be no need to post on SO.

Comment: I don't believe that comment.